# Delay while using PlaceAutocomplete without using Rest API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API. But I cannot find a way to reduce the number of requests without implementing the rest API.

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .setFilter(new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS).build())
                .build(mActivity);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    }
```

Comment: The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1,000 free requests per 24 hour period, after which it will start failing. Can you please elaborate more, what do you want to limit ? Since there is already a default limit, do you want to impose some different limit through your app ? A little more elaboration may help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are worried over the API costs. If you check the terms, you'll see you can make unlimited requests if you use the google UI (The fragment). If you want to avoid doing to many calls to the remote API, the easiest way would be calling the REST service manually, but the quota is pretty thin (1000 request each 24 hours), so you should wrap the REST api inside a webservice of your own, and call that from the app. Additionally, you should set caching in both sides (server and app), keep in mind google allows you to cache the places request for 30 days. In this case, you could decide to call the api when the user has entered a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Long way.

1. Use [JD](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/releases) to decompile jar founded in `YouProject...\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-places\9.4.0\jars`
   and Playservices apk
2. Find activity with intent filter that has action "com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.AUTOCOMPLETE"
3. Get top activity
4. Find variable and change value of that delay by java reflection.

or
Short way
Implement your [PlaceCompleteAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter) much easier :)